# SQL query difference between sum in the same rows with different conditions

Tags: sql

I want to do an arithmetic operation between the sum of two columns but with two different conditions

Example :

```
Select 
    (Select sum(amount), sum(qty) 
     from table1 
     where id = 1) - Select sum(amount), 
    sum(qty) 
from table1 
where id = 2)
```

This example doesn't work.

Can you please suggest how I can fix that?

I need a proper query can do this arithmetic operation with different sum in the same table with different conditions properly

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
DECLARE @TEMP TABLE (
    id int,
    amount int,
    qty int
)

INSERT INTO @TEMP
SELECT 1, 10, 20 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 30, 40 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 10, 20 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 30, 40

SELECT
    (amt_total1 - amt_total2) amt,
    (qty_total1 - qty_total2) qty
FROM (
    SELECT 
        SUM(CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN ISNULL(amount, 0) END) AS amt_total1,
        SUM(CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN ISNULL(qty, 0) END) AS qty_total1,
        SUM(CASE WHEN id = 2 THEN ISNULL(amount, 0) END) AS amt_total2,
        SUM(CASE WHEN id = 2 THEN ISNULL(amount, 0) END) AS qty_total2
    FROM @TEMP
) A
```

Output :

```
amt qty
0   20
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).